# Is $x^{101} + 101x^{100} + 102$ irreducible?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How can I show that $x^{101} + 101x^{100} + 102$  is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? I was not able to apply Eisenstein's criterion (Which was my first thought as 101 is prime) because of the $102$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The irreducibility of $P(x)$ is equivalent to the irreducibility
of $P(x − 1)$. Because the binomial coefficients $\binom {101}{k}$, $1 \leqslant k \leqslant 100$ are all divisible by 101, the polynomial $P(x − 1)$ has all coefficients except the first divisible by 101, while
the last coefficient is $(-1)^{101} + 101(-1)^{101} + 102 = 202$, which is divisible by 101 (and not divisible by $101^{2}$). By Eisentstein's criterion, we have that $P(x-1)$ is irreducible, which implies that $P(x)$ is irreducible. Q.E.D.

Comment: Beat me to it! $\,$

Comment: I was typing as fast as I could (my typing is terrible btw) :)